# T-Sql - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

how can we find the cost of a select statement and how can we improve the performance of a statement

Comment: I'll throw in an unsolicited plug for [SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp). Very nice **FREE** tool IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You use the execution plans for the query to see where the costs are so you can target specific areas for improvement.

There are whole books written on this subject, it is rather large so nothing short of a superficial answer can be given for such a broad question.

Start with this article - [part1](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/) and [part2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-2/) from Simple Talk (Finding the Causes of Poor Performance in SQL Server).